# Question on boundary condition for Maxwell's Equations and Coulomb's law

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, conventions, boundary-conditions, gauge-invariance

When deriving Coulomb's law using the differential forms of Maxwell's equation, the boundary condition that $\phi = 0 $ at infinity is also used.

> From $\nabla × E = 0, E = \nabla \phi$ for some $V$, plugging this in to Gauss's law we get poisson's equation $\nabla^2 \phi =  \rho/e_0$, or $\nabla^2 \phi = q\delta\lvert r-r_0\rvert/e_0$ for a point charge. The general solution is $\phi = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{q}{\lvert r-r_0\rvert} + F$ where $F$ is a harmonic function which satisfies laplace's equation. We have to invoke the condition that at infinity $\phi = 0$ for $F(x)$ to disappear and thus for Coulomb's law to follow.

Maxwell's Equations and the Lorentz force law summarize all of electrodynamics, and that boundary conditions come from the constraints in the problem of consideration. The situation in consideration is a point charge in empty space, so what physical principle motivates this boundary condition, that $\phi = 0$?

Comment: $\phi = 0$ at infinity is arbitrary, it doesnt matter, all change in potential is the same and all yield the same E field.

Comment: Look at my comments below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maxwell's equations and Lorentz force law do indeed summarize all electrodynamics. However there are physical situations in which you do not know the charge distribution a priori, but instead you specify some surfaces on which the electric field is always normal, which happens when you have metals around.

In such situations you can in principle solve the three partial differential equations for $E_x, E_y$ and $E_z$ in three variables $x, y, $ and $z$, with the specified Dirichlet boundary conditions. All that introducing the potential did to you was convert this horrible system of PDEs with Dirichlet BCs to a single PDE with Neumann BCs. So it's just a mathematical trick. All physical meaning is still in $E$ alone (classically).

Now once you agreed to introduce $\phi$ to make your life easier, you have to impose the same boundary conditions that you would have otherwise imposed on $E$ itself. For a point particle without introducing $\phi$, to solve the PDEs you had to impose $E\rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$. This implies $\phi\rightarrow $ constant as $r\rightarrow\infty$. But then we can choose this constant at our disposal because it is physically meaningless (only difference in potential is meaningful).

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can coloumb's law be derived from Maxwell's law and Lorentz's law without resorting to ambiguities or assumptions? Is there a link? Most texbooks include a proof using the integral form of Maxwell's equations, but the spherical symmetry of the electric field is assumed, without justification.

Comment: Also, would it make sense for a different boundary condition to be chosen such that $F(x)$ is a nonconstant function?

Comment: My answer was misleading, i'll edit it.

Comment: The justification for spherical symmetry when deriving coulombs law using Gauss's law is inevitable, because if a spherically symmetric charge resulted in an asymmetric electric field this would be a very nontrivial statement about the electric permittivity of the vacuum.

Comment: Thanks for the re-edit. Why does $E→0$ as $r→∞$? Do there exist situations where $E$ is not zero at $r = ∞$, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: To be precise it has to vanish at least as fast as $1/r$, because: 1- because otherwise this would imply that you can feel an electron in Andromeda. 2 - This would imply that the electric energy stored in the electromagnetic field of a small charge to be infinite (forgetting now about the energy exactly near the point charge).

Comment: A situation where $E\neq 0$ at $r\rightarrow\infty$ is the hypothetical problem you see in electrostatics where you have an "infinite" uniformly charged wire. Or an "infinite" uniformly charged sheet.

Comment: So $E$ has to vanish at $r→∞$ because otherwise conservation of energy will be violated? In other word, is the boundary condition $E→0$ as $r→∞$ motivated by the physical principle of conservation of energy?

Comment: No. It has to do with common sense and everyday experience, that a small charge cannot produce an infinite energy that permeates the entire universe.

Comment: Okay. So common sense has to be used along with Maxwell's equations to derive the Coloumb law. Does that mean that Coloumb's law isn't fully contained within Maxwell's equations and Lorentz's equation, but also with the fact that a small charge cannot produce an infinit energy?

Comment: Lets take this discussion to chat. Thank you very much for answering my inquiries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21877/discussion-between-andy-and-ali-moh).

Comment: Please note $E = 0, R= \infty$ doesnt have to be the case when considering electrodynamics. Background EM solutions can exist that are non zero, that are not limited to constant solutions, but inherend wave like solutions "tagged onto" the fields 'produced' by charged. These fields are determined by initial conditions of the universe and not the location of charges and currents.

Comment: In the context of electrodynamics, ( and technically electrostatics): We CAN also feel the fields from an electron in andromeda, otherwise we wouldn't be able to see the light from there.

Comment: Coulombs law can be derived from maxwells equations using only gauss law and assumptions. It can also be directly derived from maxwells equations and a charge density of $Q\delta^3(r)$

Answer (score 0):

Causality requires any physical effect outside the light cone of a charge to  vanish. So whether or not you believe that you can add an arbitrary constant, or a gauge field, $\phi=0$ at infinity makes sense.